# One login attends Google classroom and Microsoft Office365 in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, single-sign-on, google-classroom

I Need to Implement LMS in my asp. Net web application. I have one login account for my domain but need to attend Google classroom and Microsoft Office365 classes.

Can anyone suggest what scenario should I follow?

Comment: can you login to them independently? are you connecting with an API or through the browser?

Comment: Connecting through browser

Comment: I think there is a mechanism in Azure Active Directory to enable single sign-on across external providers.  Here are a few links to dig into (on Office 365) --- https://myapplications.microsoft.com/ - This is the link to "your enterprise applications".  

This is the link to the location in the Azure Active Directory admin portal where you can add integrations with 3rd parties.  -- https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/

Consolidate your identity situation and you win.